# Module 'PyQt6.QtWidgets' has no attribute 'QDesktopWidget'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, python-3.9, pyqt6

I try to run this code, but it always get this AttributeError, I have searched for many website but there wasn't any answer.

```
QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
AttributeError: module 'PyQt6.QtWidgets' has no attribute 'QDesktopWidget'
```

My Code:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def center(self):
        qr = Form.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())
```

I'm using PyQt6 Version 6.1.0, Python 3.9.5

Answer (score 13):

From [the docs:](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/widgets-changes-qt6.html#qdesktopwidget-and-qapplication-desktop)

> **QDesktopWidget and QApplication::desktop()**
>  QDesktopWidget was already
> deprecated in Qt 5, and has been removed in Qt 6, together with
> QApplication::desktop().
>
> QScreen provides equivalent functionality to query for information
> about available screens, screen that form a virtual desktop, and
> screen geometries.
>
> Use QWidget::setScreen() to create a QWidget on a specific display;
> note that this does not move a widget to a screen in a virtual desktop
> setup.

Then use:

```
cp = QtGui.QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().availableGeometry().center()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def center(self):
        qr=self.frameGeometry()           
        cp=QtGui.QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).